# Regex 24 hours time validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, time

I am using this regex to validate time:

```
var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
var isValid = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/.test(time);
if (isValid === false) {
    errors += '- ' + ' Invalid Time Input.\n';
}
if (errors)
    alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n' + errors);
document.MM_returnValue = (errors === '');
```

And while this works in most cases, inputs such as `9:50` are accepted. I need to enforce such that user is forced to input the leading `0` in time less that 10. i.e the valid time should be `09:50` what am I missing here?

Comment: `2[0-4]` must be `2[0-3]`. There is no `24:59` time. Also, it seems all you need is to remove `?` in `[0-1]?`, `/^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/`. Not sure you need the capturing groups at all, `/^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?$/` should be fine.

Comment: Wow, that is very helpful actually. This worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tow things:

- `2[0-4]` must be `2[0-3]` as there is no `24:59` time.
- It seems all you need is to remove `?` in `[0-1]?` as the `?` quantifier means *1 or 0 repetitions*.

Note you do not need capturing groups here since you are not using the submatches. It is advisable to replace those groups with non-capturing ones, or remove due to redundancy.

Use

```
/^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oF7I2b/1)

In your code snippet:

```
var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
var isValid = /^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?$/.test(time);
if (isValid === false) {
    errors += '- ' + ' Invalid Time Input.\n';
}
if (errors)
    alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n' + errors);
document.MM_returnValue = (errors === '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regex pattern for hours in the format "00:00" to "23:59" in JavaScript using the following regular expression:

```js
const HOURS_REGEX = /^(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$/;
```

Explanation of the regex pattern:

- **^**: Start of the string.
- **(?: ...)**: Non-capturing group to group the hour and minute parts.
- **[01]\d**: Matches hours in the range of 00 to 19.
- **2[0-3]**: Matches hours in the range of 20 to 23.
- **:**: Matches the colon between hours and minutes.
- **[0-5]\d**: Matches minutes in the range of 00 to 59.
- **$**: End of the string.

This regex will ensure that the input matches the format "**HH:MM**" where **HH** is between **00** and **23** and **MM** is between **00** and **59**. It will not match invalid hours like "**24:00**" since the valid range for hours is from **00** to **23**.

Answer (score 0):

In `/^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/` the first `?` indicates that `0-1` may appear or nor, just remove it and you force 0 or 1 to appear